# Every mathematician is a scientis but only some mathematicians are teachers

Tags: first-order-logic

I can't figure out the FOL for this question.. Need help with this question. I have tried ∀ x, ∃y mathematician(x) , mathematician (y) -> scientist (x) & teacher (y)

Answer (score 0):

∀ x (mathematician(x) -> scientist (x)) and
∃y mathematician(x)

Comment: ∀ x (mathematician(x) -> scientist (x)) and  ∃ x (mathematician(x) -> not teacher (x))